# Collecting principal variations during search and using them in ordering?

Tags: engines, programming

In an Alpha Beta search in that utilizes a Negamax framework, how does one collect principal variations to use in move ordering, and how does one use them, without using a transposition table?

Additionally, would it be different in a principal variation search, and do we collect and store important moves for quiescence search too? Please provide a code example.

Comment: I don't have time to provide a code example now. Refer to https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Principal+variation for details.

Comment: I only use TT for PVs, it's easy and efficient. Stockfish does that, why would you not use it? Anyway, I've seen people use triangular-PV, Harm Geert Muller uses it a lot. Google him and the topic and you'll see it. I don't have much experience in that.

Comment: PVS doesn't change the PV collection. It's a technique for doing more work on the PV nodes.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to store important nodes in QS. You'll need to update hashing. I update the score and bound for a move in QS.

Comment: jonathan, I'd guess that you've seen sources similar to the site referenced in the first comment. What exactly have you found lacking in whatever sources you've read before? Spelling that out a bit might help you get answers as specifically tailored to your needs as possible.

Comment: @johnanthan, in chess programming, "node" is more precise than "move". We don't say "collect moves for PV", we say "collect PV nodes".

Comment: @Jonanthan, move ordering is implicitly done by searching a PV node before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

> In an Alpha Beta search in that utilizes a Negamax framework, how does one collect principal variations to use in move ordering

Every strong modern chess engine which uses alpha-beta search uses a transposition table to store the PV move for ordering. If you are writing a chess engine, you should this high-performance, now ubiquitous technique.

> and how does one use them, without using a transposition table?

There are various approaches to storing the principal variation which are commonly used *alongside* a transposition table. The most popular of these is a triangular PV table. [The Chess Programming Wiki has a page on this](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Triangular_PV-Table), which includes code examples as you requested.

> Additionally, would it be different in a principal variation search

No. Move ordering can be implemented in the same way for both pure alpha-beta and for PVS. The only difference is the way in which the ordered moves are searched.

> and do we collect and store important moves for quiescence search too?

No. Standard techniques used to order captures are sufficient in quiescence search (namely, MVV/LVA and Static Exchange Evaluation). The move stored in the transposition table may not be a capture, so it is unlikely to be useful for quiescence.